# Webサイトが検索結果に表示されない問題について

Tags: html, html5, polymer, web-component

初めまして。
現在Webサイトを制作しているのですが、日本語で検索するとヒットせず、英語で検索すると
ヒットします。

各タグについて
titleタグ: 日本語でタイトルを入れています。
h1: 英語でタイトルを入れています。

おそらくh1タグの情報が検索結果にヒットしているのでしょうが、日本語でも検索結果に
ヒットさせたいのでしょうが、何か手段はありませんでしょうか？

Web Component(Polymer)を利用しておりそのComponent内部でh1を定義しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、GoogleやBingなどの検索エンジンの検索結果は、私達が自由に設定できるものではないことを認識する必要があります。そしてSEOはシステムやライブラリなどのドキュメントや仕様とは異なり、日々ルールが変化し、そのアルゴリズムが公開されるわけではないということも認識しておくと良いでしょう。

考えられることとして以下の可能性があると思われます。

- titleタグの文字列と検索した文字列が異なっている
- titleタグを変更してから時間が経過していない
- titleタグに設定されている文字列がユニークでない
- 文字コードの設定が誤っているため、日本語が認識されていない

加えて、h1の文字列は検索結果に影響を与えやすいという話を聞いたことがありますので、h1に日本語も加えてみるのも良いかもしれません。（今まで継続してたサイトのタイトルを変えることによるデメリットも考えられますが）

この問題は、SEOの問題になりますので、SEO診断ツールを利用すると、なにか発見があるかもしれれません。

https://ferret-plus.com/806

検索エンジンによっては、直接サイトを登録したり、クロールのリクエストを申請したりすることもできますので、そちらを試してみるのもよいでしょう。

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?rd=1

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

まず、情報が不足していた点お詫び申し上げます。

教えていただいた項目を再確認致しました。
>titleタグの文字列と検索した文字列が異なっている
同じでした。
>titleタグを変更してから時間が経過していない
約2週間です。
>titleタグに設定されている文字列がユニークでない
会社名なのである程度はユニークなのではないかなと考えます。
>文字コードの設定が誤っているため、日本語が認識されていない
文字コードは大丈夫そうでクローラーから見た場合も文字化けして
いないようでした。(Google Search Consoleより)

結果なんとか反映されたのですが、Google Search Consoleでの再クロールの申請等、多数の処理をしてしまいどの処理が効果があったのかを検証できませんでした。申し訳ありません。